# urlretrieve seems to corrupt image file

Tags: python, image, urllib

I use urlretrieve to scrape images from a web site. That works well except for one, not so minor detail. The files are not readable. I tried several websites but the result is the same. I wondered whether I should indicate it is a binary download but could not find any hint in the documentation. Searched the web, found some alternative with the requests library but again same results. The Windows Photo Viewer, Paint and Gimp all report that the file is corrupted or unreadable. I am pretty sure I am making some dumb mistake. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
def get_images(url, soup):
    #this makes a list of bs4 element tags
    print 'URL: ', url
    n = 0
    images = [img for img in soup.findAll('img')]

    #compile our unicode list of image links
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]
    for each in image_links:
        n = n + 1
        path = urlparse.urlparse(each).path
        fn = (os.path.split(path)[1]).strip()
        ext = (os.path.splitext(fn)[1]).strip().lower()
        if (fn == '' or ext == ''):
            continue

        fn = os.path.join ("images", fn)

#        print 'From: ', url
        print 'Each> ', each
#        print 'File< ', fn
#        avatar = open(fn, 'wb')
#        avatar.write(requests.get(url).content)
#        avatar.close()
        result = urllib.urlretrieve(url, fn)
        print result

    return n
```

**Update**

Jephron pointed me to the right direction, I did not correctly combine the url with the image path. His solution works by using `urlparse.urljoin(url, each)` while using `os.path.join` as I did initially, may result in suddenly having backslashed in a url on a windows system. Quite annoying. I added a test for relative and absolute url paths and the final code is shown below.

```
def get_images(url, soup):
    #this makes a list of bs4 element tags
    print ' '
    print 'URL: ', url
    n = 0
    images = [img for img in soup.findAll('img')]

    #compile our unicode list of image links
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]

    for each in image_links:
        path = urlparse.urlparse(each).path
        fn = (os.path.split(path)[1]).strip()
        ext = (os.path.splitext(fn)[1]).strip().lower()
        if (fn == '' or ext == ''):
            continue

        fn = os.path.join ("images", fn)
        if (not (each.startswith ('http:') or each.startswith('https:'))):
            image_link = urlparse.urljoin(url, each)
        else:
            image_link = each

        print 'Found: ', fn

        try:
            urllib.urlretrieve(image_link, fn)
            n = n + 1
        except:
            continue

    return n
```

Be aware however, that 3/4 of the .png's are still unreadable. I have to find out why, but there might still be a hidden snag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your code and took a look at the "image" that it downloads. Turns out that the contents of the file you save out is actually the entire HTML of the site. Try opening it in a text editor and see for yourself.

To fix this, notice that the argument you pass to urlretrieve is actually the url for the web page your scraping. If you join the image url to the page url, you get the correct url:

```
def get_images(url, soup):
    #this makes a list of bs4 element tags
    print 'URL: ', url
    n = 0
    images = [img for img in soup.findAll('img')]

    #compile our unicode list of image links
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]
    for each in image_links:
        print "maybe an image"
        print each
        n = n + 1
        path = urlparse.urlparse(each).path
        fn = (os.path.split(path)[1]).strip()
        ext = (os.path.splitext(fn)[1]).strip().lower()
        if (fn == '' or ext == ''):
            continue

        fn = os.path.join ("images", fn)

        print 'Each> ', each

        result = urllib.urlretrieve(os.path.join(url, each), fn)
        print result

    return n
```

Comment: Thanks for the trouble of running and testing my code! It pointed me in the right direction. I have edited my question with the correct solution.  Thanks a lot!